# how osgi bundles are used by sling

Tags: java, osgi, aem, sling

I am just starting on Apache sling and CQ5 development. There is this concept of using OSGI bundles in Sling.

I can't find out how the sling framework actually interacts with these bundles and where does the response from bundles go ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OSGi is module framework and service platform used by Sling and the CQ5 product.  Sling itself is comprised of a series of bundles hosted within the Felix OSGi container.  Bundles are a collection group of components/services and java classes managed by the container.  The bundle can specify which packages will be imported, exported and also the versions of those dependencies.

There are a number of ways that you can interact with OSGi from Sling.  From a JSP/JSP you can use the sling object (of type [SlingScriptHelper](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/org/apache/sling/api/scripting/SlingScriptHelper.html)), which is most likely available in your JSP page if you have included the following line:

```
<%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%>
```

in your component or have the following:

```
<cq:defineObjects>
```

You can use it like so:

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = sling.getService(QueryBuilder.class);
```

Additionally, if you have your own OSGi components (e.g. Servlet, Service, etc) you can inject references to other OSGI components/services using SCR annotations.  Bertrand describes this in his answer to [Getting OSGi services from a bundle in Sling/CQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8604678/252840). Effectively this means adding the @Reference annotation to your OSGI component variables in your components, like so:

```
 @Reference
 private SlingRepository repository;
```

When your component is loaded, then the reference will be injected by the OSGi container.

A bundle doesn't have a response as such.  A deployed bundle should be visible in the system console:

```
http://localhost:4502/system/console/bundles
```

with its components, services & configuration declared here:

```
http://localhost:4502/system/console/services
http://localhost:4502/system/console/components
http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr
```

(Replace localhost:4502 with your own CQ server host:port)

Once you have obtained a reference to a component, then you can call the methods on that and use the return values from those calls.

Comment: Thanks SO MUCH !!! I was almost losing hope on this.. The regular material on the internet does not answer this question

Comment: Documentation on the day [CQ5 developer site](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current.html#Developing%20on%20CQ) and [blogs](http://dev.day.com/content/ddc/blog/2008/05/slingosgi.html) is pretty good.  Also the [Felix / SCR](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin/scr-annotations.html) is helpful.  Finally, check out the unit/integration tests for the [Sling project itself](https://github.com/apache/sling) as these usually show the best way of using the various Sling APIs.    

Please accept the answer if it meets your needs. ;-)

Comment: Actually I have to learn CQ5 (including Sling, OSGi, Felix, bundles etc.) in 3 days !! :) So I am just rushing over webpages now. Thanks much